# How to commit changes to a branch when head is "* (detached from <tag>)"

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-commit

I want to commit and push changes to remote but I am detached from tag. How do I take just the name of the tag and form git commands that reattach the head where it was detached from, and commit and push to remote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I [...] reattach the head where it was detached from [...]?

The output of `git branch` being

```
* (detached from <tag>)
  <possibly other branches...>
```

indicates that you've run `git checkout <tag>`. Your situation is something like the following

[image]

The HEAD is pointing, not to a branch, but *directly* to a commit (the one that tag `<tag>` also points to, but that's beside the point): you're in detached-HEAD state. To reattach the HEAD, you need to make it point to a branch, which you can do by running

```
git checkout <branch-in-question>
```

However, Git will, in general, prevent you from checking out a branch if you're not in a clean working state. That's where [*stashing*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) comes in handy. Stashing is akin to tidying your desk by temporarily putting everything that's sitting on it in a drawer, only to retrieve that stuff at a later stage, when needed.

Here, you should run

```
git stash save
git checkout <branch-of-interest>
git stash pop
```

Resolve any conflict arising because of that last command. In my example above, your repo would then look like so,

[image]

with your local changes in the working tree. You can then stage those changes, commit, and push to remote.

Comment: would I be able to perform this without referencing the name of the branch and only the tag?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding something: the HEAD can only be attached to a branch, not to a tag. You'll need to specify the name of a branch somewhere if you want to reattach the HEAD.

Comment: If the tag is an instance of the branch, shouldn't just the tag be sufficient in reattaching the head?

Comment: @Emanegux No. Wait, I'm working on some diagram to explain that.

Comment: @Emanegux: the tag is not an instance of the branch.  A tag name is simply an alias for a raw SHA-1 ID.  A branch name is also an alias for a raw SHA-1 ID, but a branch name has two extra properties: (1) it's allowed to move, and (2) you're allowed to be "on the branch" by using `git checkout` with the branch-name.  When you use part 2, this augments part 1 so that the branch-name *automatically* moves to each new commit you make.

Comment: Attempting git stash save is returning the following error: 'docroot/symlink/filename' is beyond a symbolic link
fatal: Unable to process path docroot/symlink/filename.html
Cannot save the current worktree state

Comment: I was able to reattach the head to my previous branch by running git reflog, checking-out the last branch I was on and re-adding and re-committing and pushing the changes that occurred while detached.

Comment: This was extremely helpful in understanding what is going on while on a detached head. torek's answer was sufficient in solving the problem through identifying where the head got detached by running git reflog. its a tough call who gets the cake here

Comment: @Emanegux Glad torek and I could help. Who gets the checkmark doesn't really matter, as long as we can file this as "solved" `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Besides [Jubobs' (correct) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27787802/1256452), it's worth noting that git records `HEAD` updates in git's [reflog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) for `HEAD`.

You can simply run `git reflog` (no extra arguments) to see something like this (yours will likely be much longer):

```
9b7cbb3 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to v2.2.1
c5b9256 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from maint to master
c2e8e4b HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to maint
c5b9256 HEAD@{3}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
c18b867 HEAD@{4}: clone: from git://github.com/git/git
```

This shows all the movements I made in a clone of the source for git itself.  You can see that I did a `git checkout maint` and then `git checkout master` and then `git checkout v2.2.1` to get to my current "detached HEAD" state.  Here `v2.2.1` is a tag.  To get back on the branch I was on before, I can simply observe that the reflog says I moved "from master", so I just need to:

```
git checkout master
```

and I will be back on branch master.

(Note that if I had made some new commit(s) here, this would "lose" them, except that I could find them again in the reflog.  Also, if I had made changes to the work-directory, the `git checkout master` step might complain that changing to branch `master` would lose my changes.  In this case, committing, stashing, and/or making a new branch, is usually the right thing to do.)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a branch where you are, commit your changes, checkout master, and merge the new branch into master.

```
git branch my-temporary-branch
git commit -m "my temp work"
git checkout master
git merge my-temporary-branch
git branch -d my-temporary-branch
```